# Extension of Nonlinear Dynamics beyond ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics

Is there an extension of the ideas of Nonlinear Dynamics beyond Ordinary Differential Equations (ODEs), specifically a Partial Differential Equations (PDEs) "version" or more generalized, yet similar, subject area?

In particular, I'm wondering if there are extensions which use some of the same ideas and techniques, such as perturbations, multiple scales, linearization, bifurcations, chaos, and control, to name a few. One of my dynamics professors has alluded to this, mentioning that Complex Ginzburg-Landau and Nonlinear Schrodinger equations are a typical result of the perturbation analysis we do with ODEs, but applied to PDEs. However, I can't seem to find any literature about this subject.

I have done some reading on Evolution Equations, which seem to be somewhat similar to what I'm looking for, but many of the techniques for general Evolution Equations and PDEs in these texts are very different from what we use with ODEs.

I would appreciate any references to literature, either in the form of textbooks or papers, where I can learn more about these things, if they exist.

Comment: I am lost with so many abbreviations... do you really think that people understand them all? :) You should profit from looking at the best possible book for parabolic equations, by Dan Henry: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0089647. It is in the case that the theory is closer to what you mention. The other case is that of delay equations and the best reference is Hale's book http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781461298946 (this version is better than the updated version by Hale and Lunel).

Comment: Thanks for the references. I have cleaned up the question a bit to minimize unnecessary abbreviations. I didn't mention it, but I currently work with Functional, and specifically Delay systems, but I do appreciate the reference either way. I will definitely be reading more on parabolic equations, since it seems to be about what I'm looking for.

Comment: The theory of delay equations is among the most successful theories in dynamics, all works beautifully (after the 1963 work of Hale, this was the crucial departure point) and is also a very good playground to test new ideas. Since you know about them, indeed I suggest that you pass to parabolic equations first of all, since all works more or less in the same manner as for delay equations. Incidentally, in the case of hyperbolic equations one is forced to deal with weak solutions from the beginning which leads to many difficulties.

Comment: Two books you might find useful are 'Pattern Formation' by Rebecca Hoyle, which does an entire chapter on deriving amplitude equations using perturbation methods and 'Pattern Formation and Dynamics in Nonequilibrium Systems' by Greenside and Cross.